# GetVersionExW error in BDS2006

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

this works in Delphi 2009 but in TurboDelphi/BDS2006 I get an error:

> [Pascal Error] xxx.pas(117): E2033
>   Types of actual and formal var
>   parameters must be identical

```
 ...
  var
     osVerInfo : TOSVersionInfoExW;
     i : Integer;
     begin
        FillChar(osVerInfo, SizeOf(osVerInfo), 0);
        osVerInfo.dwOSVersionInfoSize:=SizeOf(TOSVersionInfoExW) ;
        if GetVersionExW(osVerInfo) then
...
```

Comment: One word of advice: Always write `SizeOf(osVerInfo)` rather than `SizeOf(TOSVersionInfoExW)` because that insulates you from hard to fathom errors when you happen to change the type of `osVerInfo` at some future point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems buggy, but in D2007 (and thus I guess also in D2006) `GetVersionExW` requires `TOSVersionInfoEx` as parameter. In D2009 this equals `TOSVersionInfoExW`, but below D2009 this is equal to `TOSVersionInfoExA`. You should go well by declaring `osVerInfo` as `TOSVersionInfoEx`. This should compile with both versions.